# Array of ASCII characters

Tags: c++, arrays, ascii, tabular

I am trying to make an array of all 32-255 ASCII characters, but I don't really think this is an array that I have created?

```
int main()
{
    cout << " ASCII 32 - 255\n";

    int col = 1;                                        

    for (int asc_char = 32; asc_char < 256; asc_char++) 
    {
        cout << std::setw(6) << asc_char << setw(3) << static_cast<char>(asc_char);

        col++;
        if (col > 7)                                    
        {
            col = 1; 
        }
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

This is how my code is now. The ASCII table comes out in an array, but not in 7 columns and 32 rows. The 32,33,34,35,36 before each character is also gone.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << " ASCII 32 - 255\n";

    unsigned char myarray[7][32] = {};
    int val = 32;
    {

        for (size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
                myarray[i][j] = val++;
            }
        }
    }
    // for (int asc_char = 32; asc_char < 256; asc_char++)
    //  cout << std::setw(6) << asc_char << setw(3) << static_cast<char>(asc_char);
     for (auto& row : myarray) {
         for (auto& col : row) {
             std::cout << col << ' ';
         }
         std::cout << '\n';
     }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There is no array in your code, you're just printing them.

Comment: I thought so too, even if I actually get the output how i want, in 32 rows and 7 columns. How in earth can a make an array of 7 columns and 32 rows and fill it with the content of all 32-255 ASCII chars?

Comment: Search for 2D arrays

Comment: @Thesar You don't need to repeat my solution in your question. The accepted answer will appear on top for everyone who's coming here with the same issue.

Comment: ASCII only has 128 codepoints. You seem to want a different character set, one that has 256 codepoints. Perhaps you intend to use the user's (console's/terminal's) current character set and hope that it defines a character for each of the 256 `char` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621704/array-of-ascii-characters/47622039#comment82201350_47621704):

> How in earth can a make an array of 7 columns and 32 rows and fill it with the content of all 32-255 ASCII chars?

You can do that as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<std::array<unsigned char,7>,32> myarray;
    unsigned char val = 32;
    for (auto& row : myarray) {
        for (auto& col : row) {
            col = val++;
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding to output the contents in a table, you probably want to use this:

```
for (auto& row : myarray) {
    for (auto& col : row) {
        std::cout << std::setw(6) << std::right << static_cast<int>(col) 
                  << std::setw(3) << std::right << static_cast<char>(col);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Here's the fully working [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99a575db523c1784)

---

The output you'll get from the above looks like:

```
    32       33  !    34  "    35  #    36  $    37  %    38  &
    39  '    40  (    41  )    42  *    43  +    44  ,    45  -
    46  .    47  /    48  0    49  1    50  2    51  3    52  4
    53  5    54  6    55  7    56  8    57  9    58  :    59  ;
    60  <    61  =    62  >    63  ?    64  @    65  A    66  B
    67  C    68  D    69  E    70  F    71  G    72  H    73  I
    74  J    75  K    76  L    77  M    78  N    79  O    80  P
    81  Q    82  R    83  S    84  T    85  U    86  V    87  W
    88  X    89  Y    90  Z    91  [    92  \    93  ]    94  ^
    95  _    96  `    97  a    98  b    99  c   100  d   101  e
   102  f   103  g   104  h   105  i   106  j   107  k   108  l
   109  m   110  n   111  o   112  p   113  q   114  r   115  s
   116  t   117  u   118  v   119  w   120  x   121  y   122  z
   123  {   124  |   125  }   126  ~   127     128  �   129  �
   130  �   131  �   132  �   133  �   134  �   135  �   136  �
   137  �   138  �   139  �   140  �   141  �   142  �   143  �
   144  �   145  �   146  �   147  �   148  �   149  �   150  �
   151  �   152  �   153  �   154  �   155  �   156  �   157  �
   158  �   159  �   160  �   161  �   162  �   163  �   164  �
   165  �   166  �   167  �   168  �   169  �   170  �   171  �
   172  �   173  �   174  �   175  �   176  �   177  �   178  �
   179  �   180  �   181  �   182  �   183  �   184  �   185  �
   186  �   187  �   188  �   189  �   190  �   191  �   192  �
   193  �   194  �   195  �   196  �   197  �   198  �   199  �
   200  �   201  �   202  �   203  �   204  �   205  �   206  �
   207  �   208  �   209  �   210  �   211  �   212  �   213  �
   214  �   215  �   216  �   217  �   218  �   219  �   220  �
   221  �   222  �   223  �   224  �   225  �   226  �   227  �
   228  �   229  �   230  �   231  �   232  �   233  �   234  �
   235  �   236  �   237  �   238  �   239  �   240  �   241  �
   242  �   243  �   244  �   245  �   246  �   247  �   248  �
   249  �   250  �   251  �   252  �   253  �   254  �   255  �
```

Note the `�` characters printed on the terminal for values grater than `126`. These are depending on the code page chosen for displaying (e.g. special latin characters like `í`,`ê`,`ü`.`ö`,etc.).

Comment: This solved the issue. You are a heroe. I am youtubing and googling for how arrays work. Was more complicated than i thought. I hope I will learn the logic behind this so I understand what you did with that code. If you have any good links with explanations feel free to share it with me. Otherwise, thank you once again @user0042

Answer (score 1):

Make the 2D array of `unsigned char`s to be able to hold values larger than `127`. Then increment the helper variable and assign the values:

```
int main() {
    unsigned char myarray[7][32] = {};
    int val = 32;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
            myarray[i][j] = val++;
        }
    }
}
```

Or the C++ way by utilizing the [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) wrapper as suggested by @user0042:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 7>, 32> myarray;
    int val = 32;
    for (auto& row : myarray) {
        for (auto& el : row) {
            el = val++;
        }
    }
}
```

To print it out use:

```
for (auto& row : myarray) {
    for (auto& el : row) {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(el) << ' ' << static_cast<char>(el) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Please note that not all characters [are printable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint).

Comment: Hey bro, winterbash's starting soon ;-)

Comment: I Tried it, but the output doesnt come in an array, it just hops by the setw sets i have chosen. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: @Thesar you tell us. Please edit your question to show your latest code

Comment: I made an answer with the update, and included a picture with the output. I did some edits in the code now, and have updated my question. The ASCII chars are lines up in an array now, but with no numbers (32,33,35,36) and are not outputed in 7 columns and 32 rows. Thank you for your answer @RemyLebeau

Comment: @Thesar that information belongs in your **question**, not in an **answer**. Please edit your question and delete your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct for 32 rows and 7 columns. You have not put cout in right position.

```
for (int asc_char = 32; asc_char < 256; asc_char++) 
{
    cout << std::setw(6) << asc_char << setw(3) << static_cast<char>(asc_char);

    col++;
    if (col > 7)                                    
    {
        cout << "\n";
        col = 1; 
    }
}
```